# Error SQL72045: Script execution error. The executed script: (While restore Database from Azure SQL)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, azure-sql-database

> 1. Error **SQL72014**: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg -2, Level 11, State 0, Line 0 Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed
>      prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
> 2. Error **SQL72045**: Script execution error.  The executed script:

This above error occurred randomly not often if try to run my script at next time it will be working fine so do you have faced or solution?

Comment: Are you running this script in DevOps? Please post the script.

Comment: no running script through .net package. actually restore database to same Azure sql server so while restore the above error occurred

Comment: If this has nothing to do with DevOps, please remove the tag. You might just have to extend your command timeout. Does it timeout at exactly the same duration every time?

Comment: don't know it was happen randomly not every time ..so need to resolved that issue but in local sql server that script was running very well .

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you,  please accept(mark) it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

As you said, the error is happened randomly not every time, it's very hard solve it.

There are many reasons may cause the error. Such as, if you restore the database from a big DACPAC file, it may take a long time and cause the Timeout error. OR if the internet environment is not unstable, Script execution also will be stopped.

What's the important is that your database has be restored successfully, don't you?

Comment: Actually it does't happen in all the time but when i restore database as .bacpac or dacpac format at very first time only ...the above error will thrown